# SIMD and object-oriented programming

Tags: c++, oop, cpu, sse, simd

I have been reading about SIMD for some time and I am going through the [slides](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/) over at Insomniac Games.

I like the idea and I am certainly open to making my code run more efficiently but I am just not clear how to get started with SIMD in terms of higher level code design.

For instance, let's assume that I am using a language low-level enough to let me know what the memory layout of arrays or classes is, e.g. C++.

If I now have a class such as **User** with attributes user_id or user_name, as a person modelling the domain that I am in, I know that I will be able to put users into hashmaps, or perhaps into arrays, vectors, or maybe sets, all depending on a particular use-case that a given User is needed in.

That is, I have a reusable User object and what data structure these objects are in is something independent of the User class's own internal structure.

Now, all the SIMD guides say, and I understand why, that instead of arrays-of-structures I should be using structures-of-arrays.

This makes sense as far SIMD instructions go but I cannot find a way to reconcile it with the fact that I am not starting with an array-of-structures that I can easily turn into a structure-of-arrays. Instead, I am starting with User. Sometimes users - in the sense of references to User objects - will be in arrays, sometimes in hashmaps, sometimes in other containers.

But this is not a scenario that online guides mention - all of them just say to turn AOS into SOA and again, I understand why, it is just that it is not a starting position of mine.

I feel that there is a gap that I just cannot make a leap over because I cannot find more complex examples. For instance, maybe I should keep user-related data in, say, two places, one is the User object for general ad-hoc access and another in SOA for SIMD instructions?

- Put more generally, how does one model more object-oriented design into SIMD?
- Or do people designing entire applications with SIMD in mind do not adhere to such OO concerns at all, instead opting for more data-oriented design?
- Or perhaps SIMD is limited to selected modules in one's codebase and such a translation between OOP and SIMD takes place in runtime when needed (i.e. the actual data is kept both in User objects and in SOA and there is manual code to keep them in sync).

I would appreciate it if people with SIMD experience could shed more light on it from a higher level perspective. Thank you.

Comment: A "User" is probably not going to go well with SIMD. SIMD is great, but its applications are limited to repeating the same basic instruction on multiple pieces of data, typically already stored in an array. This is used for mathematic operations; so I can't see how a User would be used with SIMD.

Comment: Normally you would use explicit SIMD (the compiler will try to auto vectorize) only in the hot loops of you program. You first need to find this loops and then you can see if you can apply SIMD.
Explicit SIMD without reason is probably a waste of time.

Comment: In this particular case I am thinking about intrinsic instructions but that aside - based on the guides I have found I think I understand when to use it, and that User objects do not map to SIMD as they are. But I am just not sure how I should go about lowering from OOP into SIMD, e.g. do I keep data around in two places? In User instances because who knows when they will be needed and what for and also in SOA because I know there is a very hot loop that will benefit from SIMD? And then I just keep both in sync myself?

Comment: For the data you want to be able to use SIMD on efficiently, yes you need to think about how that data will be stored.  (And *what* operations will probably be performance critical, and which data they need).  That will inform your decision of when to optimize data layouts for SIMD brute force.  (And the tradeoff of non-sequential access to that data touching more cache lines than if it were AoS.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, so essentially, with User, this is a generic object reusable in ad-hoc scenarios that I may not envision at a time when I create this class. With SIMD I am focused on what kind of operations will benefit from it specifically and I lay out data in SOA accordingly, likely as a copy of original objects, e.g. if I am to increase some counters on User objects and it is a hot path I can do it with SIMD because it will operate on several User objects at a time. But this is a narrow and specific use-case so I need to think about specific operations and specific data layout for it.

Comment: You can still ad-hoc access particular objects by index (and store that index in data structures etc), you just wouldn't have them in a format that C++ recognized as object

Comment: One possible approach is to make User a view, which is only used to access user properties and represent the user. The User class would not own any data and would be effectively a reference into a container of users. That container can store users' data in a SIMD-friendly manner internally and implement vectorized operations on users. This way you keep OO-style interfaces with the rest of your code through User, avoid data duplication, and implement mass operations using SIMD.

Comment: If you have a complex CPU-bound algorithm that needs to process many users, you can create a class like `UserBatch4` to keep 4 users in the SOA form in registers, with SIMD vectors instead of arrays. Also write a function to create/deconstruct and/or load/store these batches.

Comment: Thank you everyone, these are all nice suggestions. If someone wanted to combine them all in a single answer, adding some more suggestions along the way, I would be happy to accept it as an answer. Thanks.